# Document block taking no parameters

Tags: ruby, block, yard

I'm writing my first gem which I'm documenting with YARD. I've made one of my classes have a constructor which expects a block which takes no arguments<sup>1</sup>.

YARD provides the `@yield [params] description` tag to describe a block argument in terms of the parameters a method will pass to it, but it doesn't format properly if the `params` list is empty. How should I document a block with no parameters?

<sup>1</sup>: Technically, I'm not even `yield`ing to the block; I have code that looks like this:

```
def initialize(&block)
  define_singleton_method(:create, block)
  create
  class << self; undef_method :create; end
end
```

...so the block contains code to be run in the context of the newly-created object. If this is a terrible idea for some reason, I'd be glad to know that, too :)

Comment: Thanks to @sawa for the edit, but the question is primarily about the YARD documentation, not the block-usage pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an [old issue](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/120) on YARD's github page; it looks like the parameters block should just be omitted:

```
# @yield Description of the block here
def initialize(&block)
  define_singleton_method(:create, block)
  create
  class << self; undef_method :create; end
end
```